# Using Onclick to call a nested function

Tags: javascript, function, nested-function

I want to implement a basic timer program that starts a 15 second timer on start button and stops on stop button

Here is what I have done so far

JS

```
 var timeleft = 15;
 function timer(){
     var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
         if(timeleft <= 0){
             clearInterval(downloadTimer);
             document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Finished";
         } else {
             document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
         }
         timeleft -= 1;
     }, 1000);

     function timerstop(){
         clearInterval(downloadTimer);
     }
 }
```

HTML

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
<button onclick="timer();">start</button>
<button onclick="timerstop();">stop</button>
```

The reason I had to use the nested function approach was to access the variable downloadtimer, the start button works as expected but on clicking the stop button I get the following error

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: timerstop is not defined
```

I would like to know if is this is a programming error or should I change my approach

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Declare `downloadTimer` and `timerstop` outside of `timer` function. Everything an inline listener refers, must be globally accessible.

Comment: Off topic - `setInterval(..., 1000)` doesn't fire exactly after 1000 ms. To achieve acurate timing you should consider subtracting two `Date.now()` results (one stored when the start button is clicked and the second one exectuted at the time of the interval callback).

Comment: The variable `downloadTimer` is out of context when you call `timerstop()`. You will have to declare it globally or pass it in to the second function

Answer (score 1):

Move downloadTimer outside.

```
var timeleft = 15;
var downloadTimer;

function timer() {
    downloadTimer = setInterval(function () {
        if (timeleft <= 0) {
            clearInterval(downloadTimer);
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Finished";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
        }
        timeleft -= 1;
    }, 1000);

}

function timerstop() {
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer